# Customise Textview of included layout

Tags: android, android-layout, include, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling

I have a layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/logos_background">
        </ImageView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/logo_background"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/logoDetails"
                android:text="Test Logo details"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stockQuantity"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/logoDetails"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:text="x10"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to include this layout multiple times in another layout which I have done as follows:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_below = "@+id/selectLayout"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/viewpager_item_layout"/>
        <include layout="@layout/viewpager_item_layout"/>
        <include layout="@layout/viewpager_item_layout"/>
        <include layout="@layout/viewpager_item_layout"/>
        <include layout="@layout/viewpager_item_layout"/>
        <include layout="@layout/viewpager_item_layout"/>
        <include layout="@layout/viewpager_item_layout"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This gives the the following result:
[image]

The problem is I need to access the text views and image views in each `<include>`.  So the logo image will be different the test logo details will be different and the 'x10' will be different for each one as I hope to populate them from a database.  Could anyone shine a light on this?

It had been my intention to use a view pager for this but that doesn't work as it takes up the whole width and height of the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<include android:id="@+id/news_title"
         layout="@layout/viewpager_item_layout"/>
```

Try if it helps.

You can access like this :

```
View includedLayout = findViewById(R.id.news_title);
TextView insideTheIncludedLayout = (TextView )includedLayout.findViewById(R.id.logoDetails);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, without sound stupid, how can I access my textview/imageviews for each include by adding an Id to the include?  If you wouldn't mind explaining I'd really appreciate it

Comment: @DJ-DOO check my updated answer. Also Rachamani also gave same answer i think. you can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

after setting layout to `include` tags , in your code use this :

```
   View v = findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
   TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
```